# Error in Hibernate FullTextSession

Tags: spring-mvc, session, hibernate-search

I have prepared a Spring MVC application, where I use Hibernate Search, alongwith

the CRUD operations.

The CRUD operations are working fine, but when I apply Hibernate Search,

```
 it gives me an error : HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HSEARCH000178: Unable to create a FullTextSession from a null Session
```

I have used the FullTextSession Class

My Code :

////////////////////////Controller///////////////////

```
@RequestMapping("/search")
    public ModelAndView search(String query, Model model,HttpServletRequest req) throws InterruptedException
    {
        String name = req.getParameter("name");
        String address = req.getParameter("address");
        String salary = req.getParameter("salary");
        String gender = req.getParameter("gender");
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        model.addAttribute("address", address);
        model.addAttribute("salary", salary);
        model.addAttribute("gender", gender);
        List<Person> searchResults = null;
    searchResults = ps.search(query);
        model.addAttribute("searchResults", searchResults);
        return new ModelAndView("search");
    }
```

//////////////////////DAOImplementation////////////

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked", "deprecation" })
public List<Person> search(String text) throws InterruptedException{

     fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
    try {
        Transaction tx = fullTextSession.beginTransaction();
        org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Person.class ).get();
        org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = qb.keyword().onFields("name", "address", "salary","gender").matching(text).createQuery();
        org.hibernate.Query hibQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(query, Person.class);
         List result = hibQuery.list();
         Iterator<Person> it = result.iterator();
         while (it.hasNext()) {
               Person p = (Person) it.next();
               System.out.println(p);
              }
              tx.commit();

    }
    finally{
        session.close();
    }


return null;
}
```

//////////////////////search.jsp///////////

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"
    prefix="springForm"%>
     <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Search Page</title>
</head>
<body>

  <ol>
    <li th:each="person : ${searchResults}">
      <b><span th:text="${person.name}"></span></b> - 
      <span th:text="${person.address}"></span> -
      <span th:text="${person.salary}"></span>
      <span th:text="${person.gender}"></span>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <springForm:form action="/MainAssignment3/search" method="GET"
        commandName="person">
    <tr>
                <td>Enter Search Text:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="text">
                <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="/MainAssignment3/search"></input>              </td>



            </tr>
        </springForm:form>
  <table border="1">
<tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <td>name<springForm:errors path='${person.name}' /></td>    
        <td>address<springForm:errors path='${person.address}' /></td>
    <td>gender<springForm:errors path='${person.gender}' /></td>        

    <td>salary<springForm:errors path='${person.salary}' /></td></tr>   
 <c:forEach var="p" items='${searchResults}' varStatus="status">
    <tr>

        <td>${p.id}</td>
        <td>${p.name}</td>
        <td>${p.address}</td>
        <td>${p.gender}</td>
        <td>${p.salary}</td>

    </tr>

</c:forEach> 


</table>

  <p th:if="${searchResults.isEmpty()}">
    <strong>Hint</strong>: the query "<a href='/search?query=any'>any</a>" 
    should return some results.
  </p>

</body>
</html>
```

/////////////////////////////stacktrace////////////////

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HSEARCH000178: Unable to create a FullTextSession from a null Session
    org.hibernate.search.Search.getFullTextSession(Search.java:38)
    com.dao.PersonDAOImpl.search(PersonDAOImpl.java:116)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:280)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.search(Unknown Source)
    com.service.PersonServiceImpl.search(PersonServiceImpl.java:45)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy41.search(Unknown Source)
    com.controller.MainController.search(MainController.java:66)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: Your session is null. Look into the Server logfile for more informations

Comment: By server logfile, you mean the stacktrace?

Comment: Yes the stacktrace in Server log

Comment: Can't figure out. I have included my stacktrace in my question

Comment: any ideas about this?

Comment: where you create the session?

Comment: The error is on the line org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Person.class ).get();

Comment: any suggestions????